# How does the app make use of Background: Location and Background: Audio?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Apologies if I am asking a silly question. Apple has rejected my App on metadata rejection and put below comments.

How does the app make use of Background: Location and Background: Audio?

Can anyone please explain what does this mean and what do I have to do to sort out this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you have designated that your app uses those two background modes but they can't find how your app uses them. So they are asking you how your app uses those modes. You are not allowed to use those background modes unless your app actually uses them for their designated purposes.

If you don't actually need those background modes, turn them off for your project in Xcode and resubmit your app for review after submitting an updated binary.

If you do need those background modes, then reply to Apple's query and tell them how your app uses them.

Comment: Thanks Rmaddy, really appreciate your answer. which two modes they are talking about? I think its only Audio right?

Comment: Read the message. It's location and audio.